# Implementing "fetch_and_inc" operation for a shared multi-threaded program in C++

Tags: assembly, cross-compiling, alpha-cpu-architecture

I am trying to cross-compile an x86 multi-threaded code for Alpha architecture. The only problem that I am facing is with implementation of the `fetch_and_inc` operation, since it is implemented as inline assembly function for x86. So, it has some x86-specific instructions which are directly copied to the assembly code by cross-compiler and then the cross-compiler tries to assemble them to the object code, but it doesn't recognize those instructions.

I think I have two options: either to implement the `fetch_and_inc` operation in c++ rather than assembly, or to replace the x86 assembly code with its equivalent Alpha code.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to perform the second proposed option: "replace the x86 assembly code with its equivalent alpha code". I dug up this explanation of how to implement fetch&inc on an Alpha CPU:

http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/82final/5841/5841pro_018.html#ldx_stx

What version of which compiler are you using? Certain compilers have high level atomic intrinsics. If your compiler supports such a feature, that should greatly simplify this task.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The cross-compiler uses a gcc version 4.3.2. I actually found an instruction which apparently serves the purpose: "__sync_fetch_and_add" . But I am not sure if it's safe to use it, I mean is the atomicity preserved after compilation or no.

Comment: I find that function in the gcc manual under atomic intrinsics. That sounds like what you'll want to use. Otherwise, it would be indistinguishable from simply writing "i++;".